# Handle errors inside promise scope funcions

Tags: javascript

I have an async function which return promise
In this promise I have scope function and inside that I have 2 other scope functions
If I try to throw error on function `a` the code continues it`s execution

```
    async someAsyncFunc(): Promise<void> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        let port: any;
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        let writer: any;
        const test = async () => {
          const a = async () => {
            throw new Error();
          };

          const b = async () => {
            // do some work
            await a();
          };

          try {
            await b();
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }

          resolve();
        };

        try {
          test().catch((err) => {
            console.log("catch block error");
            console.error(err);
            reject(err);
          });
        } catch (error) {
          return reject(error);
        } finally {
        }
      });
    }
```

I want somehow to handle all errors that could happen on either functions a,b and load at
this final try catch block of the returned promise

```
try {
    test().catch((err) => {
        console.log("catch block error");
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
          });
        } catch (error) {
          return reject(error);
        } finally {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>       try {
>         await b();
>       } catch (err) {
>         console.log(err);
>       }
> ```

You're catching and handling the error there.

You can't get it in `test()`'s catch handler because no error is raised to that point.

It's already been handled.

You'd need to throw it again if you want something else to catch it:

```
  try {
    await b();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention - catch block of await b() is not caught

Comment: "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.8.min.js:1:13924
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.8.min.js:1:10866"

Comment: Drat. Saved the version before I cleaned out the TypeScript: https://jsbin.com/hubanikeze/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Weird. I simplified my code for the question, But for me its not caught. I also tried to remove the try catch block and saw the the one who calls the someAsyncFunc does get the reject with the error message, but the execution of 'test' continues

Comment: You're not going to get a solution to your problem if you ask a question about some code you've simplified to the point where it doesn't exhibit your problem.